# Git does not commit

Tags: git

I try to commit my changes and I keep getting this:

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

I do:

```
git add .
git commit -a -m "test"
```

and I get the error message before I can do git push

Comment: That means you don't have any changes.  Check gitignore.

Comment: what is the output of `git status`?

Answer (score 2):

Like the message says, it doesn't look like there are changes to add to the cache, let alone commit anything. Execute `git status` to see if changes even exist (it shouldn't).